# how can i import java class to gradle script?

Tags: android, properties, build, gradle

i want import java class to gradle script.

let's see script below.

----------build.gradle------------------

```
import com.my.project.MyProperty;

apply plugin: 'maven'


/**--- Version ---*/
project.group = 'com.my.project'
project.version = MyProperty.VERSION
```

---

----------MyProperty.java---------------

```
public class MyProperty {
  public static String VERSION = "1.0.0";
}
```

---

please give me a hand!

Comment: Is your build script referencing a class that's being built by the script?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

self Answer :

when i use "project.version = '0.0.3'" in gradle file, also project version is show up in BuildConfig.java.

so, i using BuildConfig.java's value when i need.